# How to excute mysql query in php echo?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to excute mysql query in php echo clause.. please help..

```
mysqli_query($mysqli2,$update_book); ----> does not work.
```

here is my code..

```
$mysqli2=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bookDB");

$update_book="UPDATE bookinfo SET Status ='No' WHERE BookName='Step by Step'";


 echo "<script language=javascript>
   var con_test = confirm('Are you ready?');
   if(con_test == true){
     mysqli_query($mysqli2,$update_book);
     alert('Complete.');
   }
   else if(con_test == false){
     alert('Canceled.');
   }
   </script>";
```

Comment: May I ask you why?

Comment: Why you need that ???

Comment: I wanto to chage database state by ok button..

Comment: Share your html code here

Comment: just working in php page..     is it impossible??

Comment: You can do it with ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute php code in a Javascript  code.

You either need to use ajax (call a php file from the js code, check http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for example), or redirect to another page when your confirm is clicked